# Different between template and templateUrl in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, directive

When I was coding with angular 1.5.3.
This is the code:

app.js

```
var testApp = angular.module('test-app', ['plugin.template']);

testApp.run(function ($rootScope) {

});

createDirective('directiveOne');
createDirective('directiveTwo');
createDirective('directiveThree');

function createDirective(name) {
  testApp.directive(name, function () {
    return {
      template: '<div>Hello<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
      // templateUrl: 'template.html',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      compile: function (element, attr) {
        console.log(name + '指令的compile...');
        return {
          post: function (iScope, iElm, iAttr, ctrl) {
            console.log(name + '指令的postlink...');
          },
          pre: function () {
            console.log(name + '指令的prelink...');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

}
```

plugin-template.js

```
(function (app) {
  try {
    app = angular.module("plugin.template");
  }
  catch (err) {
    app = angular.module("plugin.template", []);
  }
  app.run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
    "use strict";

    $templateCache.put("template.html", "<div>hello<div ng-transclude></div></div>");
  }]);
})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh" ng-app="test-app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="../dist/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="plugin-template.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<directive-one>
    <directive-two>
        <directive-three>

        </directive-three>
    </directive-two>
</directive-one>

</body>
</html>
```

In the function `createDirective` , when comment out   `// templateUrl: 'template.html',`。

```
      template: '<div>Hello<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
      // templateUrl: 'template.html',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
```

Here's the log :

```
directiveOne指令的compile...
directiveOne指令的prelink...
directiveTwo指令的compile...
directiveTwo指令的prelink...
directiveThree指令的compile...
directiveThree指令的prelink...
directiveThree指令的postlink...
directiveTwo指令的postlink...
directiveOne指令的postlink...
```

when comment out `// template: '<div>Hello<div ng-transclude></div></div>',`

```
      // template: '<div>Hello<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
```

Here's the log :

```
directiveOne指令的compile...
directiveOne指令的prelink...
directiveOne指令的postlink...
directiveTwo指令的compile...
directiveTwo指令的prelink...
directiveTwo指令的postlink...
directiveThree指令的compile...
directiveThree指令的prelink...
directiveThree指令的postlink...
```

when comment out all as :

```
// template: '<div>Hello<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
// templateUrl: 'template.html',
// transclude: true,
// replace: true,
```

Here's the log :

```
directiveOne指令的compile...
directiveTwo指令的compile...
directiveThree指令的compile...
directiveOne指令的prelink...
directiveTwo指令的prelink...
directiveThree指令的prelink...
directiveThree指令的postlink...
directiveTwo指令的postlink...
directiveOne指令的postlink...
```

the order of 'compile', 'prelink' ,'postlink' changed when I comment out some code as above.

Why does this comes ? 
Can you explain the different between template and templateUrl ,and the different between use transclude and don't use transclude in a directive ?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> ## templateUrl
>
> This is similar to `template` but the template is loaded from the specified URL, asynchronously.
>
> Because template loading is asynchronous the compiler will suspend compilation of directives on that element for later when the template has been resolved. In the meantime it will continue to compile and link sibling and parent elements as though this element had not contained any directives.
>
> The compiler does not suspend the entire compilation to wait for templates to be loaded because this would result in the whole app "stalling" until all templates are loaded asynchronously - even in the case when only one deeply nested directive has `templateUrl`.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - templateUrl](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-)

Comment: So is it a unrecoment way that use templateUrl in directive which container any other directives ?